# Как удаленно установить ПО на выделеный сервер под Windows?

Tags: windows

Есть VDS под управлением Windows(не windows-сервер).
Есть ли возможность как-то установить свое ПО на него програмно? Таких VDS много и на каждый заходить по RDP не удобно.

Если ли какие-то встроенные средства, что бы запустить на нем что-либо с привилегиями?

Comment: Ну я на свои рабочие машины накатываю софт с помощью `ansible`.

Comment: Это решение подходит для win-сервера? Разве это решение не требуется предварительно выполнять какие-то операции на удаленной машине ручками(установка чего-то на удаленной машине)?

Comment: Сейчас я устанавливаю нужный софт с помощью SharpRDP. Но это довольно корявое решение с имитацией нажатий клавиш и все такое. 
Неужели нет решения, как установить что-то не подключаясь по RDP ни разу.

Comment: Ну тебе нужен настроенный `winrm`. А по управлению конкретно виндой - есть куча готовых модулей: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/list_of_windows_modules.html